# Why can't I submit form with jQuery's .submit() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I've created one CTP file in CakePHP. In that I've created one form with the submit button.

```
<?php echo $form->create(BILLING_DETAIL, array('url'=>'/fbilling_details/subscription/','id'=>'billing'));?>
<?php echo $form->submit('SAVE', array('type'=>'submit','name'=>'saveSubscription', 'id'=>'saveSubscription','onclick'=>'return confirm_subscription('."'".$billing_info[0][ACCOUNT_TYPE]['tx_acc_name']."'".','."'".$billing_info[0][PLAN]['nu_actual_price']."'".')')); ?>
```

And my function for JavaScript is somewhat like this:

```
function confirm_subscription(plan_name,mon){

        // confirm dialog
        jQuery.jqDialog.confirm("Current Plan&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;"+plan_name+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+mon,
                function() {

                    jQuery("#billing").submit();
                    //return true; 


                },      // callback function for 'YES' button
                function() { 
                    return false;
                }       // callback function for 'NO' button
        );
        return false;   

  }
```

But I can't submit the form with this. Please anybody can help me.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [JQuery sumbit methods](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) binds a function to the submit event. To submit the form itself, you should call the submit method of the form element.

```
 $('#billing').get(0).submit();
```

Comment: +1, if the form has unique id i guess `$("#billing").submit();` would do

Comment: It didn't worked in my case. I think the issue's somewhat different.

Comment: Do you have other elements that also have the id 'billing'? Maybe other Javascript errors? What if you use the browsers developer tools to inspect the document and the javascript? The difference between jquery.submit and Javascript.submit is an actual problem, but it doesn't need to be the only problem.

Comment: @GolezTrol Can you give me alternative of this scenario ?

Comment: @AmitMerchant Not really. The code you have shown looks OK at first sight, but it is a mere fraction of your complete app. Hard for me to guess what's wrong.

Comment: @3nigma I think you're then calling the submit function on the jQuery object, which is actually the problem in OP's original code.

Comment: @GolezTrol Does it cause a problem because I've taken it in jqDialog's function ?